# Speed and acceleration problem

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

There is a road with length l meters. The start of the road has coordinate 0, the end of the road has coordinate l.

There are two cars, the first standing at the start of the road and the second standing at the end of the road. They will start driving simultaneously. The first car will drive from the start to the end and the second car will drive from the end to the start.

Initially, they will drive with a speed of 1 meter per second. There are n flags at different coordinates a1,a2,…,an. Each time when any of two cars drives through a flag, the speed of that car increases by 1 meter per second.

Find how long will it take for cars to meet (to reach the same coordinate).

Can anyone please help me how to proceed with this question?

Comment: Please help anyone.

Comment: Please can U show what have you tried.

Comment: Let's suppose both reaches at x distance from 1st car. So I am calculating the time taken for car 1 and car 2 to reach at that position. 1 more equation I am getting from time being equal for them

Comment: it looks like the cars will meet at the midpoint so the problem can be simplified to one car going half the distance.

Comment: Two equations and two variable then I am trying to solve for both variables

Comment: @Vasya how can u say that they meet at mid point.any proof?

Comment: Can anyone answer.